# Can we use SPFx for App part properties build using SharePoint Add-in

Tags: sharepoint-addin, spfx, app-part

Is there a possibility to apply the SPFx framework using dynamic dropdowns for App Part properties built within SharePoint Add-in?
Thanks!

Comment: welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution